# Looking for integrate-with in grails 3.x

Tags: grails

the command

```
grails integrate-with --foo
```

is gone in grails 3.x. Has that functionality not been implemented yet, or is it hiding somewhere I don't know where to find it?

Comment: IDE's like eclipse and intellij can recognise grails projects automatically these days, so my guess is that things like `integrate-with --eclipse` isn't really needed anymore.

Comment: That does make sense. I never used it for IDE integration, but I found `integrate-with --git` handy. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no need for the IDE integration command, but an auto-generated `.gitignore` file is definitely nice to have and something that was missing in the early 3.x releases.

Since Grails 3.0.5, a `.gitignore` file is created by default with the `create-app` command.

See the GitHub issue: [Default integration with Git on grails create-app command](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9108).